# How to make my receipt on POS printer align

Tags: c#

object TicketItem have 3 properties:

```
string Quantity
string Name
string Price
```

I need to have format like this on 70mm space on paper like below.

```
----------------------------------
1 x Coca Cola 0,25            4,00
2 x Fantasime                11,00
3 x Some long string item   222,99
    name into wrap item
----------------------------------

foreach (var item in ticket.ticketItems)
        {
            itemString = FormatLineItem((item.quantity.Length == 1 ? item.quantity + "  " : item.quantity), item.name, item.price);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(itemString, printFont, Brushes.Black, x, y);
            y += lineOffset;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Environment.NewLine, printFont, Brushes.Black, x, y);
            y += lineOffset;
        } 

public string FormatLineItem(string quantity, string name, string amount)
        {
            return string.Format("{0}x {1,-10} | {2,5}", quantity, name, amount);
        }
```

My results isn't like in EXAMPLE top please someone solution.

Comment: your code includes an attempt at graphical text output, and one at string alignment for fixed-width raster output. which one is needed?

Comment: @dlatikay that code example coca cola etc.. need solution for all wraped text and align prices to right etc.. can't make it work ...

Comment: What is your current output look like?

Comment: if you are using GDI+ for printing, it could work when you set a fixed-width (non-proportional) font on the device. Otherwise, you have to draw multiple stretches of text with different alignment settings.

Comment: If you don't use a fixed-pitch font then you need two DrawString() calls, the second one using a different x argument.  Do keep in mind that POS printers always like raw output that bypasses the printer driver, you get the fixed-pitch font that's built in the printer as a side-benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add yourself a length checking function?

```
public string FormatLineItem(int quantity, string name, string amount)
{
        return string.Format("{0} x {1}{2}", 
                 EnsureLength(quantity,2,true), 
                 EnsureLength(name,23,true),
                 EnsureLength(amount,7,false));
}
private string EnsureLength(string input, int requiredLength, bool padRight)
{
    if (input.Length > requiredLength) return input.Substring(0, requiredLength);
    if (input.Length == requiredLength) return input;
    if (padRight)
    {
        return input.PadRight(requiredLength);
    }
    else
    {
        return input.PadLeft(requiredLength);
    }
}
```

My debug trace below... Are you not using a fixed width font?  You'd need to check for very long things to make the extra line still...

```
 "1  x Coca Cola 0,25            4,00"
 "2  x Fantasime                11,00"
 "3  x Some long string item   222,99"
```

Comment: My debug trace added to answer for formatting reasons... Are you not using a fixed width font?

Comment: what happend if 3 string item is longer then that size.. how to wrapp on last space in that lenght and put another part of string bellow the third first part of item.
This is fine solution but need word wrap now for middle.

Comment: Put in a check function Need2ndLine(name) that checks the length, if it says you need a 2nd line, then do another formatted line of output to print the 2nd half of the info.